# Mat-tab angular-localize proper way to translate

Tags: angular, localization, angular-translate, angular-localize

Lets say i have mat tam created like this

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="nameToBeTranslated">
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

How can i translate that label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="{{'nameToBeTranslated' | translate}}">
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

or

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab [label]=" 'now you can use pipes here' | anyPipeForTranslation">
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Thank you but i am not sure if it is for same version my normal translates looks like this <button.... i18n="@@translate-text">Text</button> Yeah i mistaken names of packs this is angular localize sorry.